# Getting Error: Column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

When adding rows to a table I am getting *Error: column does not exist* and I am not sure why. I know the table does and it is fairly straight forward. Here is what I have to add and here is what the table looks like. Any help would be great and let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Whatever value I have in `emailField` it is giving me the error that emailfield column does not exist

```
final String addemployee = "insert into employee values ('" + name_field.getText() + "', '" + usersSuper.getText() + "', '" + true + "' , md5('" +    passwordField.getText() + "') , "  + emailField.getText() + ");";
```

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  name text NOT NULL,
  manageremail text,
  isadmin boolean NOT NULL,
  userpassword text NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "user_Email" PRIMARY KEY (email)
)
```

Comment: you've missed quotes around emailField.getText()? it should be `'" + emailField.getText() + "'`

Comment: Not sure how I missed that one but thanks for your help Roman!

Comment: i hope you are only storing salted hashes and not real passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
final String addemployee = "insert into employee values ('" + name_field.getText() + "', '" + usersSuper.getText() + "', '" + true + "' , md5('" + passwordField.getText() + "') , '" + emailField.getText() + "');";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed quotes around emailField.getText()? it should be `'" + emailField.getText() + "'`